# How to paste multiple yanked words by vim-visual-multi to another place to one line

Tags: vim, neovim

I would like learn easily work with multiple lines. So my goal is copy multiple words an paste to another place. And I am working with `mg979/vim-visual-multi`

All my steps:

1. My start code:

```
import test from './test';

export default {
  test,
}
```

2. I adding a few imports so I do just `yy4p`:

```
import test from './test';
import test from './test';
import test from './test';
import test from './test';
import test from './test';

export default {
  test,
}
```

3. Change imported file names

```
import test from './test';
import test from './test_one';
import test from './test_two';
import test from './test_three';
import test from './test_four';

export default {
  test,
}
```

4. Then replace `test` to new file names. On fourth `t` `ctrl+down`. Where `[t] - selected cursors`

```
import test from './[t]est';
import test from './[t]est_one';
import test from './[t]est_two';
import test from './[t]est_three';
import test from './[t]est_four';
```

5. Then `ctrl+n` for mark any selected line and yank `y`
6. Then move selected cursors to second `t`

```
import [t]est from './test';
import [t]est from './test_one';
import [t]est from './test_two';
import [t]est from './test_three';
import [t]est from './test_four';
```

7. `ctrl+n` and `p` in result:

```
import test from './test';
import test_one from './test_one';
import test_two from './test_two';
import test_three from './test_three';
import test_four from './test_four';

export default {
  test,
}
```

8. And on this step I want to replace contain of default so I select second `t` cursor `ctrl+down` and `ctrl+n` and `y` and `Esc` - for exit from `mg979/vim-visual-multi`

```
import [t]est from './test';
import [t]est_one from './test_one';
import [t]est_two from './test_two';
import [t]est_three from './test_three';
import [t]est_four from './test_four';
```

9. After go to line (`3j`) where `test` in default and `viwp` so in result I see another yanked value

```
export default {
  another_yanked_value,
}
```

So, how to yank multiple words and paste to another place?

I would like in the final as:

```
import test from './test';
import test_one from './test_one';
import test_two from './test_two';
import test_three from './test_three';
import test_four from './test_four';

export default {
 test, 
 test_one, 
 test_two, 
 test_three, 
 test_four, 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Vim doesn't do multi-cursors on its own, hence the need to use a third-party plugin.

The trouble, here, is that all the yanking and pasting you do in steps 1-8 is handled by the plugin, not by Vim. In step 9, you are back with regular Vim, which a) doesn't handle multi-line yanking/putting like the plugin does, and b) probably doesn't have access to the plugin's internal registers anyway.

You should check the plugin's documentation and use its issue tracker to see if the maintainer can help you get what you want.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I'm using (vim-visual-multi)[https://github.com/mg979/vim-visual-multi/tree/master/doc] plugin and I didn't find the answer for my question.

Comment: You won't find it here. Open an issue in the plugin's issue tracker.